# Use animation to change position of an object

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I want to make Jenga tower and main problem is how to 'relax' every block to get stable construction. When I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> I get an animation of a system, when blocks fall down on the plane - how to save this system and use as a new background for operations? It would simplify a lot my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With selected object hit `space` and type "bake to keyframes", open `Graph editor` (at the left down corner of application), delete everything before and after interesting moment, then clear all keyframes - it will "freeze" the moment of simulation.

Comment: How to open Curve editor?

Comment: Sorry, to be particular, it is actually `Graph editor`, `Curve editor` is one of its modes, using for keyframe-based animation.

Comment: Okay, one more thing - it is not quite best solution, because after using it I can't generate any other object. Could you test it and say how to deal with it?

Comment: Sorry,  don't understand well "after using it I can't generate any other object". Please tell more.

Comment: I created box with Active Rigid Body physics and a plane with Passive Rigid body. Ok. I used "Baked to keyframes" to generate falling of a box to the plane. I deleted from Graph Editor all points except last. After this I even have box where I wanted to, but I can't manipulate it, after Alt+A and Esc it gives exactly same position before manipulation. Even worse, I can't add another box without vanishing it after Alt+A and Esc.

Comment: Make it active rigid body again and start animation from 1st frame again. Or use button `Bake all dynamics` instead `Alt-A`: Properties editor (right vertical panel in default UI layout) -> Scene -> Rigid body cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25698/discussion-between-daniil-romanov-and-cheshire-cat).